# Can I store Type or Type name in Dictionary and use it in generic method in C#?

Tags: c#, dictionary, struct, types

I try to parse byte arrays to several structures.

I have a UDP package with `StructureTypeID` and `StructureByteArray` inside.

Also I have structures:

```cs
//StructureTypeID == 1
public struct Dog{}
//StructureTypeID == 2
public struct Cat{}
//StructureTypeID == 3
public struct Rat{}
```

I have a simple generic method:

```cs
public static T ByteArrayToStruct<T>(byte[] ByteArray){}
```

I tried something like this:

```cs
Dictionary<int, Type> StructTypes = new Dictionary<int, Type>(3)
{
  {1, Dog},
  {2, Cat},
  {3, Rat},
};

StructTypes[StructureTypeID] ParsedStructure = ByteArrayToStruct<StructTypes[StructureTypeID]>(StructureByteArray);
```

or

```cs
Dictionary<int, string> StructTypes = new Dictionary<int, string>(3)
{
  {1, "Dog"},
  {2, "Cat"},
  {3, "Rat"},
};

Type StructType = Type.GetType(StructTypes[StructureTypeID]);
StructType ParsedStructure = ByteArrayToStruct<StructType>(StructureByteArray);
```

I also tried to store generic method in dictionary, but I failed to define Func type:

```cs
Dictionary<int, Func<byte[], SomethingHere>> ByteArrayParsers = new Dictionary<int, Func<byte[], SomethingHere>>(3)
{
  {1, ByteArrayToStruct<Dog>},
  {2, ByteArrayToStruct<Cat>},
  {3, ByteArrayToStruct<Rat>},
};

var ParsedStructure = ByteArrayParsers[StructureTypeID](StructureByteArray);
```

None of them works.

I can use simple `if .. else` of course, but I thought maybe there is a way to do that more elegant way.

Comment: Think about what you are trying to do: you are trying to call a strongly typed method based on a value only known at runtime; that's never going to work.

Comment: You probably want to make a parent type called animal that these all inherit from --  then you can have a function act on that type

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay Well I thought this is a point of using generics. That no one knows what type it will work with until it called with one. Now I see that I was wrong.

Comment: @Hogan I tried it as well. But I stuck with `struct` type (due legacy code) which in my knowledge is not inheritable.

Comment: I don't understand your problem, but in any case using shapes are animals is given as an example in every single article or book about object oriented design -- there must be some examples you can look at?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you can store type objects in a dictionary by using `typeof`:

```
Dictionary<int, Type> StructTypes = new Dictionary<int, Type>(3)
{
  {1, typeof(Dog)},
  {2, typeof(Cat)},
  {3, typeof(Rat)},
};
```

But you can;t use variables in the delcaration of a generic type, so `ByteArrayToStruct<StructType>` will not work. You'll need to use [`Type.MakeGenericType`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.makegenerictype?view=netframework-4.8) to get an instance of the generic type.  Note, however, that the *compiler* will still not know what the generic type is, so it's not clear if this will be any better than a large switch statement.

Comment: I almost forgot about `switch`. But yeah I think you are right: there is no point to reinvent the wheel. Thank you. I will stay with `switch` statement.